# Getting "Unable to start the daemon process" when running old project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I have a laptop: hp pav dv6 4 gb ram 32bit win 8. This is what I get when I tried to run an old project.

Error message:

> Unable to start the daemon process. This problem might be caused by
> incorrect configuration of the daemon. For example, an unrecognized
> jvm option is used. Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the
> daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.4/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
> Process command line: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_261\bin\java.exe
> -Xmx1536m -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp C:\Gradle\gradle-4.1\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.6.4-all\ankdp27end7byghfw1q2sw75f\gradle-5.6.4\lib\gradle-launcher-5.6.4.jar
> org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 5.6.4 Please read
> the following process output to find out more:
> ----------------------- Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap
> ----------------------- Check the JVM arguments defined for the gradle process in:
>
> - gradle.properties in project root directory
> - gradle.properties in in GRADLE_USER_HOME directory

gradle.properties:

```
## For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
#
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
#
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
#Wed Nov 18 01:37:38 PST 2020
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512m
systemProp.http.proxyHost=
systemProp.http.proxyPort=80
systemProp.https.proxyHost=
systemProp.https.proxyPort=80
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

invalidate cache restart and changing default value can make run project